# Changed colors after using AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have a problem in my app. It's a phonebook. After using AsyncTask all the colors change!

This is screenshot before using AsyncTask:

[image]

This is screenshot after using AsyncTask:

[image]

Whats wrong with my app?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz9S4.png): 
My code(with AsyncTask):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
private ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
private DbWorker db;
private ListView listView;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    new DbAsyncTask(context).execute();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeContactActivity.class);
            Contact contact = contactAdapter.getContact(position);
            intent.putExtra("name", contact.getContactName());
            intent.putExtra("phone", contact.getContactPhone());
            intent.putExtra("category", contact.getContactCategory());
            intent.putExtra("org", contact.getContactOrgName());
            intent.putExtra("id", contact.getContactId());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

class DbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Contact>> {
    private Context ctx;

    public DbAsyncTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        db = new DbWorker(ctx);
        contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) db.selectAllContacts();
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ctx, contacts);

        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }
}
```

}

Without AsyncTask I commit:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
context = getApplicationContext();
new DbAsyncTask(context).execute();
```

and add:

```
db = new DbWorker(this);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) db.selectAllContacts();
contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, contacts);
listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing application's context to your async which doesn't have a clue about your theme/style. Instead you should use activity context which possesses required theme/style information.

Hence, replace:

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

With the following:

```
context = this;  /*here 'this' refers to your activity's context*/
```

Comment: Or basically new `DbAsyncTask(this).execute();`

Comment: @MuratK. yes of course. but I thought to answer the least change :)

Comment: @waqaslam. Thanks you